# Does Leeloo have telepathic powers?

Tags: the-fifth-element

In *The Fifth Element*, when the general taunts Leeloo, she stares him in the eye and his eyes look a bit hypnotized before she growls and punches through the tube.

A few moments later, she sort of stares at the scientist/medic as she considers her way out and then somehow knows/assumes that she can jump through the wall to her escape. Everyone else seems to be unaffected.

Is this meant to be evidence of some sort of telepathic power that is otherwise abandoned later in the movie?

Comment: I always understood the situation such that she is much better at reading other people's reaction. So, the slightest odd look from a person knowing the weak spot in the room will be registered by her, and she will act accordingly. Also, the doctor obviously was positively impressed, hence it is more likely that he would give unconscious clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the transcript, the [novel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061058386) and the [earlier version of the script](http://www.angelfire.com/tx2/leeloo/5thelement.txt), I've come to the conclusion that whilst Leelo does possess several clearly superhuman abilities (genetic intelligence, the ability to learn incredibly quickly and physical strength) telepathy isn't one of her gifts.

There *are* a number of telepathic characters in the film; **The Diva** communicates with Leelo and her assistant without using words, "**Mr Shadow**"'s voice causes Zorg great pain and **the Mondoshawans** knock a human unconscious with a look

I see no obvious *in-universe* barrier to her having telepathy (especially since her DNA is apparently a mix of alien and human) other than that she simply wasn't written that way.